# VSCode and PHP (hurdles)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm coming from an eclipse world, and I've experienced some hurdles, adapting to VS Code. Assume I'm opening a new document, adding  to the start and end of the document, saving it as "test.php" and doing the following:

1. I type "echo $_SERVER" and at no point does it complete (or hint completion) for this very common predefined array, nor does it show (or hint showing) the server variables.
2. If i require a script with classes in it, VS Code can find the methods of the class. If i require a script that, itself, requires all of my classes, VS Code can't find anything (for hinting, go-to declaration, etc.)
3. If i start typing "in_array", it's suggested almost right away, but not the arguments (haystack, needle)

The extensions I have installed are: PHP Extension Pack 1.0.1, PHP Formatter 0.2.4, PHP IntelliSense 1.4.3.

And for user @jay-blanchard, the "duplicate" you linked does not answer any part of this question.

Comment: `$_SERVER` is an array, so you should `print_r($_SERVER);` or `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: I see, so in VS Code, you cannot type: echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and expect it to do any completion? That's a big impediment, i would say.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client this plugin resolves the issue.